# Fechar janela do console em C

Tags: c, linux, windows, terminal, console

Preciso criar o jogo da velha. Quero saber como fechar a janelinha preta que aparece sem precisar clicar qualquer tecla, por exemplo:
Ao executar o programa aparece:

> 1 para jogar
>
> 0 para sair

Se o usuário digitar 0 quero que o programa feche totalmente sem precisar clicar em Enter.

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com [uma pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641021/how-to-make-a-c-console-program-exit-with-exit-function):

> O console (ou shell) em que o programa está sendo executado é totalmente independente do seu programa, ele é só uma interface de usuário (I/O). Tentar fechar o console não é uma boa ideia - ao invés disso você deveria inicializar o seu programa sem amarrá-lo(attached). (isso é fácil no ambiente Unix, mas mais difícil em Windows)

Em **Unix** você deve olhar sobre o comando [`kill(2)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/kill/).
Em **Windows** você precisa executar um comando matando o processo pelo seu nome: [`system("taskkill /IM cb_console_runner.exe")`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc725602(v=ws.10).aspx).